# what is the alternative to NVL function in MS Access 2007

Tags: sql, ms-access

I wrote an SQL query in MS Access

```
select NVL(count(re.rule_status),0) from validation_result re, validation_rules ru where re.cycle_nbr="+cycle_nbr+" and re.rule_response=ru.rule_desc and re.rule_status='FAIL' and ru.rule_category='NAMING_CONVENTION' group by re.rule_status"
```

But the output is `Null`. I want to convert it to `Zero`. If I use `NVL` function then MS Access does not accept it. I tried `NZ` function also but that also gives the same output, i.e NULL instead of Zero.

Answer (score 13):

`Nz()` is definitely the function you're looking for. You say that you tried it and it returned `Null`, but I find that hard to believe because the whole point of `Nz()` is to ***not*** return `Null`. For reference:

`x = Nz(Null, 0)` returns 0 (`VbVarType.vbInteger`)

`x = Nz(Null, "")` returns an empty string (`VbVarType.vbString`)

`x = Nz(Null)` returns an empty variable (`VbVarType.vbEmpty`, *not* `VbVarType.vbNull`)

### Edit

Further investigation shows that the problem in your particular case is that you are doing a `COUNT(re.rule_status)` in a query that also does `GROUP BY re.rule_status`. If the `WHERE` clause of the query results in an empty set (no rows returned) then the overall query simply returns no rows instead of a single row with a value of 0 or Null.

This can be verified with the following test code...

```
Sub NzTest()
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset, strSQL As String
strSQL = "SELECT Nz(COUNT(LastName), 0) FROM Members WHERE False GROUP BY LastName"
Debug.Print strSQL
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenSnapshot)
If rst.EOF Then
    Debug.Print "No rows were returned."
Else
    Debug.Print "Count = " & rst(0).Value
End If
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
End Sub
```

...which produces the result

```
SELECT Nz(COUNT(LastName), 0) FROM Members WHERE False GROUP BY LastName
No rows were returned.
```

When the `GROUP BY` is removed we get...

```
SELECT Nz(COUNT(LastName), 0) FROM Members WHERE False
Count = 0
```

...and in fact `Nz()` is not even required in that case:

```
SELECT COUNT(LastName) FROM Members WHERE False
Count = 0
```

Comment: Note that `Nz()` is limited to queries that are run from within Access itself.  For example, a stored query that uses `Nz()` will not work if you try to run it from outside Access (e.g., if you try to import the data from the query into Excel).  An equivalent (but more verbose) construct that will work in both cases is `IIf(IsNull(<expression>),<value if null>,<expression>)`.

Comment: Can u give the syntax of NZ

Comment: I tried NZ(expression,0) but it did not work and I am getting an empty field as an output