# Unable to Display 0 or Null in MS Access Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to run a sql query in MS Access. I have  tables/queries that I am trying to join.

1. MonthlyTargets_0_SPARTN_qry selects informaion from SPARTN_Livefeed1
2. SPARTN_Livefeed1 contains tests that have been completed by supervisors.
3. REF_TestCatalog_tbl - a list of test numbers and description
4. REF_TestCategory_tbl - a list of categories (buckets that each test number falls into)

The query is working correctly, except that I need to show "0" if no tests were comlpeted for the month.
see row 4 in Expected Results, the supervisor has not done any tests in category 4 for 1/1/2020- (no record
in SPARTN_Livefeed1 for this supervisor doing a test number 134)

```
MonthlyTargets_0_SPARTN_qry

SELECT SPARTN_Livefeed1.*, DateValue(Month([Date]) & "/1/" & Year([Date])) AS ComplianceMonth
FROM SPARTN_Livefeed1;
```

```
SPARTN_Livefeed1
Sheet ID         Date          Test Number          Supervisor ID
OB-1234          1/1/2020         101                 806855
OB-5678          1/1/2020         101                 806855
OB-9877          1/1/2020         112                 806855
OB-5644          1/1/2020         123                 806855
OB-5644          1/1/2020         123                 806855
```

```
REF_TestCatalog_tbl
ID          TestId          TestDesc          TestCategory          StartDate          EdnDate
1             101            Stopping              1                 12/1/2019
2             112            Delay                 2                 12/1/2019
3             123            Documents             3                 12/1/2019
4             134            Radio                 4                 12/1/2019
```

```
REF_TestCategory_tbl
ID        CategoryID          CategoryDesc          StartDate          EndDate   
1             1               Signals               12/1/2019
2             2               Speed                 12/1/2019
3             3               Equipment             12/1/2019
4             4               Operation             12/1/2019
```

```
Expected Results
CategoryID          TestofficerID          Actuals          ComplianceMonth
1                   806855                 2                 1/1/2020
2                   806855                 1                 1/1/2020
3                   806855                 3                 1/1/2020
4                   806855                 0                 1/1/2020
```

MAIN QUERY

```
SELECT    REF_TestCategory_tbl.CategoryID, 
               MonthlyTargets_0_SPARTN_qry.[Supervisor Id] AS TestOfficerID, 
               Count(MonthlyTargets_0_SPARTN_qry.[Sheet ID]) AS Actuals, 
               MonthlyTargets_0_SPARTN_qry.ComplianceMonth
FROM MonthlyTargets_0_SPARTN_qry 
INNER JOIN 
            (  REF_TestCategory_tbl 
                      INNER JOIN REF_TestCatalog_tbl ON REF_TestCategory_tbl.CategoryID = REF_TestCatalog_tbl.TestCategory) ON MonthlyTargets_0_SPARTN_qry.[Test Number] = REF_TestCatalog_tbl.TestID
GROUP BY REF_TestCategory_tbl.CategoryID, MonthlyTargets_0_SPARTN_qry.[Supervisor Id], MonthlyTargets_0_SPARTN_qry.ComplianceMonth
ORDER BY REF_TestCategory_tbl.CategoryID;
```

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16828310/what-is-the-alternative-to-nvl-function-in-ms-access-2007

Comment: No, because there is no null or 0 returned at all

Comment: What is the actual result of your current query? (or did I miss it?)

Comment: CategoryID          TestofficerID          Actuals          ComplianceMonth
1                   806855                 2                 1/1/2020
2                   806855                 1                 1/1/2020
3                   806855                 3                 1/1/2020

Comment: "I need to show "0" if no tests were comlpeted for the month" but your expected result have the same ComplianceMonth ? What do you mean when you say "for the month" ?

Comment: I am trying to show how many tests in each category has been completed. So if o tests were done in category 4 for 1/1/2020, I need it to show 0.  The current query does not return anything for category 4 for 1/1/2020

Comment: And this query you have provided works ?

Comment: The query is working but not returning the row with 0 in Actuals
```
CategoryID          TestofficerID          Actuals          ComplianceMonth

1                   806855                 2                 1/1/2020
2                   806855                 1                 1/1/2020
3                   806855                 3                 1/1/2020
4                   806855                 0                 1/1/2020
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208145/discussion-between-tom-and-vboka).

Comment: The sql is executing as is